# Having 3 where clauses in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have 3 where clauses in LINQ, but its failing - I tried this

```
List<string> companies = new List<string>() { "0001001429"};
List<string> roleIDs = new List<string>() { "1486334", "1419282"};


var q = (from up in UserReports
        where up.UserType == "Internal"     
        where companies.Contains(up.CompanyId) && roleIDs.Contains(up.RoleId)
                             select new 
                             {
                                 UserId = up.UserId,
                                 FirstName = up.FirstName,
                                 LastName = up.LastName, ...});
```

I also tried to have 2 joins -

```
var q = (from up in UserReports
                             join c in companies on up.CompanyID equals c
                             join r in rolesIDs on up.RoleId equals r
                             where up.UserType == "Internal"
                             select new 
                             {
                                 UserId = up.UserId,..});
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Regards,
Bhavik

Comment: failing ... could you be a bit precise on that part

Comment: Failing, as in its not compiling neither its giving results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I changed the "where" with an "and"

```
var q = (from up in UserReports
    where up.UserType == "Internal"     
    && companies.Contains(up.CompanyId) && roleIDs.Contains(up.RoleId)
                         select new 
                         {
                             UserId = up.UserId,
                             FirstName = up.FirstName,
                             LastName = up.LastName, ...});
```

And you need to specify the id of the companies and roles:

```
var q = (from up in UserReports
                         join c in companies on up.CompanyID equals c.Id
                         join r in rolesIDs on up.RoleId equals r.Id
                         where up.UserType == "Internal"
                         select new 
                         {
                             UserId = up.UserId,..});
```

Comment: For 1st answer, i am getting the following error - Delegate 'System.Func<DbModel.UserReports,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments I had copied Where twice by mistake in the question :) Let me try 2nd solution. Which of the above is better? in terms of performance.

Comment: The first one will be compiled as a `IN` sql clause, I guess it will be the best one.